# Calling another function from within an event listener's function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a number of `.nextBtn` elements and I've added click listener to each of them. I'm trying to implement a functionality where if the `img` is clicked, `takeToNextPage()` is called. For some reason it's not working.

```js
let nextBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.nextBtn');
for (let i = 0; i < nextBtn.length; i++) {
  nextBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('.nextBtn')) {
      takeToNextPage();
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="page1 page">
  page 1
  <div class="nextBtnContainer">
    <div class="nextBtnText">some text</div>
    <div class="nextBtn" id="1">
      <img src="assets/game-15.png" alt="Next">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="page2 page">
  page 2
  <div class="nextBtnContainer">
    <div class="nextBtnText">Play Mind Reader</div>
    <div class="nextBtn" id="2">
      <img src="assets/game-15.png" alt="Next">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: Please don't suggest adding event listener to `img`. I don't want to do that. Also, the actual number of `.textBtn` elements are more than shown. So solution should probably be scalable.

Comment: _"So solution should probably be scalable."_ - Solution should probably use _event delegation_.

Comment: I'm already using that. I've clarified my language in the question now. The answer I'm looking for is how to call a function, from within the function that we call in an event listener.

Comment: _`classList.contains('.nextBtn')`_ - classes don't contain leading dots. You are confusing a class name with a class selector here.

Comment: "I'm already using that." It's obvious you don't know what CBroe is talking about. You're attaching a click event to each element with the class `nextBtn`. Trust me that is NOT event delegation.

Comment: Thanks for answering guys. Because of your comments, I went ahead and looked at Event Delegation concept again and realised I got it all wrong. I shouldn't be attaching handlers to each of the elements. Got something out of a silly mistake. :)

Answer (score 0):

class should not have . in the beginning

```
let nextBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.nextBtn');
for(let i = 0; i<nextBtn.length; i++){
  nextBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if(e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('nextBtn')){
      takeToNextPage();
    }
  });
}
```